# is there any way to detect count of pages any word document created by PhpWord?

Tags: phpword

By PhpWord how detect count of pages, it is really very big problem

create word document by using PhpWord and unzip created document but in unzipped file at app.xml file does not contain page property. I scanned all of site relevant but i could not find the solution